# Find most common offender in audit.log

Tags: audit, linux-audit

I have a situation where a clean install of RHEL 8.8 and having `auditd` running with a given `/etc/audit/rules.d/audit.rules` file produces a `/var/log/audit/audit.log` that is greater than 4GB.  This is with me having the only user account on the system, me being the only person logged in, and doing a `cp -rp /data/*  /backup/`.  FWIW I am logged in on the backup server (server-B) with `/data` NFS mounted (from server-A) on it when I am doing the `cp -rp`.  The `/data` folder has greater than 50TB of data.  The file system is XFS_4.0 from RHEL 7.9 on `/data` and XFS_5.0 from RHEL 8.8 on /backup; both server A & B are running RHEL 8.8.

Is there a linux [audit] tool that can parse out the most common entries in `audit.log` ?

And, based on description above if a reason and solution could be provided that would be cool too.

```
# /etc/audit/rules.d/audit.rules

## First rule - delete all
-D

-e 2

## Increase the buffers to survive stress events.
## Make this bigger for busy systems
-b 8192

## This determine how long to wait in burst of events
--backlog_wait_time 60000

--loginuid-immutable

## Set failure mode to syslog
-f 1

-a always,exit -F path=/usr/bin/newgrp -F perm=x -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k priv_cmd

-a always,exit -F arch=b32 -S execve -C uid!=euid -F euid=0 -k execpriv
-a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S execve -C uid!=euid -F euid=0 -k execpriv

-a always,exit -F arch=b32 -S execve -C gid!=egid -F egid=0 -k execpriv
-a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S execve -C gid!=egid -F egid=0 -k execpriv

-w /etc/shadow -p wa -k identity
-w /etc/security/opasswd -p wa -k identity
-w /etc/passwd -p wa -k identity
-w /etc/gshadow -p wa -k identity
-w /etc/group -p wa -k identity
-w /etc/sudoers -p wa -k identity
-w /etc/sudoers.d/ -p wa -k identity
-a always,exit -F path=/usr/bin/su -F perm=x -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k privileged-priv_change
-a always,exit -F arch=b32 -S setxattr,fsetxattr,lsetxattr,removexattr,fremovexattr,lremovexattr -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k perm_mod
-a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S setxattr,fsetxattr,lsetxattr,removexattr,fremovexattr,lremovexattr -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k perm_mod

-a always,exit -F arch=b32 -S setxattr,fsetxattr,lsetxattr,removexattr,fremovexattr,lremovexattr -F auid=0 -k perm_mod
-a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S setxattr,fsetxattr,lsetxattr,removexattr,fremovexattr,lremovexattr -F auid=0 -k perm_mod

-a always,exit -F path=/usr/bin/chage -F perm=x -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k privileged-chage
-a always,exit -F path=/usr/bin/chcon -F perm=x -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k perm_mod
-a always,exit -F path=/usr/bin/ssh-agent -F perm=x -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k privileged-ssh
-a always,exit -F path=/usr/bin/passwd -F perm=x -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k privileged-passwd

-a always,exit -F path=/usr/bin/mount -F perm=x -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k privileged-mount
-a always,exit -F path=/usr/bin/umount -F perm=x -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k privileged-mount

-a always,exit -F arch=b32 -S mount -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k privileged-mount
-a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S mount -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k privileged-mount

-a always,exit -F path=/usr/sbin/unix_update -F perm=x -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k privileged-unix-update

-a always,exit -F path=/usr/sbin/postdrop -F perm=x -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k privileged-unix-update

-a always,exit -F path=/usr/sbin/postqueue -F perm=x -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k privileged-unix-update

-a always,exit -F path=/usr/sbin/semanage -F perm=x -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k privileged-unix-update

-a always,exit -F path=/usr/sbin/setfiles -F perm=x -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k privileged-unix-update

-a always,exit -F path=/usr/sbin/userhelper -F perm=x -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k privileged-unix-update

-a always,exit -F path=/usr/sbin/setsebool -F perm=x -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k privileged-unix-update

-a always,exit -F path=/usr/sbin/unix_chkpwd -F perm=x -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k privileged-unix-update

-a always,exit -F path=/usr/libexec/openssh/ssh-keysign -F perm=x -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k privileged-ssh

-a always,exit -F path=/usr/bin/setfacl -F perm=x -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k perm_mod

-a always,exit -F path=/usr/sbin/pam_timestamp_check -F perm=x -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k privileged-pam_timestamp_check

-a always,exit -F path=/usr/sbin/pam_timestamp_check -F perm=x -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k privileged-pam_timestamp_check

-a always,exit -F arch=b32 -S init_module,finit_module -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k module_chng
-a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S init_module,finit_module -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k module_chng

-a always,exit -F arch=b32 -S rename,unlink,rmdir,renameat,unlinkat -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k delete
-a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S rename,unlink,rmdir,renameat,unlinkat -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k delete

-a always,exit -F path=/usr/bin/gpasswd -F perm=x -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k privileged-gpasswd

-a always,exit -F arch=b32 -S delete_module -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k module_chng
-a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S delete_module -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k module_chng


-a always,exit -F path=/usr/bin/crontab -F perm=x -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k privileged-crontab

-a always,exit -F path=/usr/bin/chsh -F perm=x -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k priv_cmd

-a always,exit -F arch=b32 -S truncate,ftruncate,creat,open,openat,open_by_handle_at -F exit=-EPERM -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k perm_access
-a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S truncate,ftruncate,creat,open,openat,open_by_handle_at -F exit=-EPERM -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k perm_access

-a always,exit -F arch=b32 -S truncate,ftruncate,creat,open,openat,open_by_handle_at -F exit=-EACCES -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k perm_access
-a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S truncate,ftruncate,creat,open,openat,open_by_handle_at -F exit=-EACCES -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k perm_access


-a always,exit -F arch=b32 -S chown,fchown,fchownat,lchown -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k perm_mod
-a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S chown,fchown,fchownat,lchown -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k perm_mod

-a always,exit -F arch=b32 -S chmod,fchmod,fchmodat -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k perm_mod
-a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S chmod,fchmod,fchmodat -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k perm_mod

-a always,exit -F path=/usr/bin/sudo -F perm=x -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k priv_cmd

-a always,exit -F path=/usr/sbin/usermod -F perm=x -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k privileged-usermod

-a always,exit -F path=/usr/bin/chacl -F perm=x -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k perm_mod

-a always,exit -F path=/usr/bin/kmod -F perm=x -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k modules

-w /var/log/lastlog -p wa -k logins

-w /var/log/faillock -p wa -k logins
```

Comment: It depends on the format (XML or flst tect) of your `audit.log`. [Edit] your Question and show the first 6 lines (`head  n 6 audit.log`). If it's flat text, the traditional text tools (`cut`, `grep`, `sed`, `sort`, `uniq` can handle your need.

Comment: in `auditd.conf` log format = RAW,  if that helps